# osx Lion Web Server 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: apache, configuration, osx-lion

I need to use the integrated webserver in osx Lion, but I got a very strange error.

With some files, and only with some of them, it returns me error 403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access /~mattiazeni/atc.mp3 on this server."

I can't understand why it gives me this error ONLY with some files and not with all of them! For example now it gives me the error with some pictures .jpg and some .mp3, but I can access other .jpg and .mp3, so the problem is not the extension type.

I try to set the config file like this, but the error remains.

```
<Directory "/Users/user/Sites/">
Options Indexes MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably the [file permissions](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/help/faq/permissions.html) are set such that webserver isn't allowed to read some of the files.

`chmod` the files to give the user Apache runs as permissions to read them.

Comment: Thanks, changing permission on each file worked. It's possible to change permissions on all the files in a directory using chmod?